# Do I really need X11 for R on Mac?

Tags: r, macos, x11, macos-mojave, xquartz

R version 3.5.2

macOS version 10.14.2 mojave

Whenever installing an R, package I see the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Everything seems to work fine. ggplot2 plots get drawn,...etc.

Do I really need to install X11 from XQuartz? 
Is anything actually broken?

Does it "unlock" anything?

Comment: If you don't try to do anything with it, not really. [It's not hard to install with homebrew](https://community.rstudio.com/t/edit-and-read-table-on-r-for-mac/5536/10?u=alistaire), though, if necessary.

Comment: thanks @alistaire I do have homebrew installed. Is there an X11 package?

Comment: It's not an R package, it's an application. See the link; basically all you need is `brew cask install xquartz`

Answer (score 4):

this may work:

brew install --cask xquartz

Answer (score 1):

For those of us who do not have (or do not want to have) an extra package management system like Homebrew on their Macs: you can download a "real" macOS `pkg` package for XQuartz from [the XQuartz site](https://www.xquartz.org/index.html). Then you just install it like any other Mac package (hint: double-click on its icon in the Downloads folder :-) ).

Installation fixes the R problem the OP asked about (tried on Big Sur).